# AWS React UI Deployment into S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, user-interface, amazon-s3

We are creating React build using npm run build command and by that we are getting build folder created. after that we are pushing build folder content to S3 bucket and also enabled the bucket for website hosting. now we are using VPCE to make sure security remains intact but the problem here is when we try to hit the URL having index.html for the first time it loads static index.html and it do not trigger any js files or API calls. when we click on some button which triggers API call it loads the data. how do we handle the situation where it gets the data on the first load itself.

We are expecting to load the data on the first load itself when we hit the URL with index.html in it.
We tried adding index.html in properties files section and still it is loading only static index.html file
please help us to get this resolved.

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: No errors in console as I told you it opens a page as static content

Comment: I’ve sometimes hit issues deploying the build folder to s3 when using copy command. Using sync tends to work better (something to do with encryption of the bucket content). With regards to the loading of data and API call, it sounds like this could be an issue with the application itself. Does it behave in the same way when running locally?

Comment: @dannyrc Actually when I run it locally it runs fine because I run it as localhost:3000 and when I try to hit localhost:3000/index.html it behaves same as showing static index.html content. My concern here is instead of hitting URL with index.html do I have to hit the root URL. If I hit using root URL which is with VPCE it gives Access Denied. not sure what is the correct approach and resolution

Comment: @dannyrc In my case I am passing my build folder content to platform team and they are  uploading build folder content to S3 bucket